# jQuery Ajax run, Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have script following:

```
var price_option_oc = 0;
// Example
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    processData: false,
    dataType: "text",
    url: mainURL + url_ajax_get_prices_oc,
    data: JSON.stringify(datas),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
}).done(function(data) {
    console.log('{1}=' + data);
    price_option_oc = data;
});

console.log('{2}' + price_option_oc);
```

Why result is, I dont know why, please explain for me

```
{2}0
{2}0
{1}=9
{1}=9
```

Why not is:

```
{1}=9
{1}=9
{2}0
{2}0
```

Thanks.

Comment: Because you are doing an asynchronous call. Just set `async:false`, then it will behave like your expectation. But this is a bad way of handling this issue.

Comment: ajax requests are asynchronous, while the request is running the code will continue running `console.log('{2}' + price_option_oc)` and when the request will complete it will call the callback

Comment: Thanks, so, now i need add async:true to my code?

Comment: ajax is called to server first ,in that mean time, outside of ajax console is runs first

Comment: Thank you. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call). I will check again. It is ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax requests run asynchronously to the rest of your code. That is, they run in parallel.

So it's very likely that

```
console.log('{2}'+price_option_oc);
```

is running before the ajax call completes and runs `console.log('{1}='+data);`

I say "very likely" because, since the ajax call relies on external factors like network speed and the response speed of the remote server, you can't guarantee how fast it will run, and therefore you can't guarantee the order things will run in.

If you need to run code which depends on the response from an ajax call, then you must put that code into your `.done` function (or into a function which is called from there).

P.S. I would not use `async:false` to solve this type of issue - this will cause the browser to stop responding to any user input until the ajax call completes (or fails). If the call takes longer than normal, it will look to the user like their browser has crashed. This is not user-friendly. Most coders don't use this feature for that reason.

Comment: Thanks, I have read 
 
"Possible duplicate of How do I return the response from an asynchronous call? – Andreas 2 mins ago". It is ok

Comment: Try to set async: false in ajax({}).

Comment: @DavinderKumar have you read my section (right above your comment) on why `async:false` is bad? The answer that this question has been deemed a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call also has a long and even better explanation of why `async:false` is almost always a terrible idea